# "Attribute provided with no value" error - UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following error :

> Attribute provided with no value

The error is from line:

```
var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

Here is my code :

```
function getArray() {
  var newData = new Array();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_id').getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var urls = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var fromText = '<span class="nb-shares">';
  var toText = '</span>';

  for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
    var url = urls[i];
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var scraped = Parser
                   .data(content)
                   .from(fromText)
                   .to(toText)
                   .build();
         newData.push([scraped]);
  }

  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('my_id').getSheetByName('Sheet5'); 
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[1].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: What line is the error coming from?  Look in the Execution Transcript under the View menu.  Put a 'Logger.log('scraped: ' + scraped)` statement right after the `scraped` line, then run the code and VIEW the LOGS.  There is no `Parser` class in Apps Script.  What is that?

Comment: `Attribute provided with no value: url (line 10, file "Code")`. Here is the line10 : `var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();` I guess I has nothing to do with my urls.length...

Comment: You might run `Logger.log(url)` and see if you're getting valid URLs.

Comment: I got the error when accidentally the wrong function was selected in the drop down in the Apps Script editor and I tried to run it. A function was selected that needed the url parameter was selected and obviously you cannot run that function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getValues()` method returns a 2 dimensional array.  You are not getting the value out of the inner array.

Currently:

```
var url = urls[i];
```

Should be:

```
var url = urls[i][0];
```

You need to add the `[0]` index for the inner array.

Answer (score 0):

If your suspicion is that urls is not a proper array than you can just console.log(urls) after you define it and see if it is an array or something else.

Or test like this console.log(Array.isArray(urls))

Comment: Google's version is Logger.log()