# How to solve common errors in Google Apps Script development

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps-script-addon

> The Q&A is currently a subject of [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398230/what-to-do-with-how-to-solve-common-errors-in-google-apps-script-development) discussion, do participate. The current plan is to split where possible into Q&As. Answers to the A&A are community wiki and the question should become one when the status is resolved.

---

**Preface**

This Q&A strives to become a collection and a reference target for common errors encountered during development in Google Apps Script language in hopes to improve long-term maintainability of [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) tag.

There are several similar and successful undergoings in other languages and general-purpose tags (see [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441049/common-errors-while-writing-android-project), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them), [php again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php?rq=1)), and this one follows suit.

---

**Why it exists?**

The amount of questions from both new and experienced developers regarding the meaning and solutions to errors encountered during development and production that can be effectively reduced to a single answer is substantial. At the time of writing, even running a query only by language tag yields:

- "Cannot find method" [8 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20cannot%20find%20method)
- "Cannot read property" [9 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20Cannot%20read%20property%20%27)
- "Cannot call ... in this context" [5 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20from%20this%20context)
- "You do not have permission" [11 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20You%20do%20not%20have%20permission)

Linking to a most relevant duplicate is hard and time-consuming for volunteers due to the need to consider nuances and often poorly-worded titles.

---

**What it consists of?**

Entries in this Q&A contain are designed to provide info on how to:

- parse the error message structure
- understand what the error entails
- consistently reproduce (where applicable)
- resolve the issue
- provide a link to canonical Q&A (where possible)

---

**Table of Contents**

To help you navigate the growing reference please use the TOC below:

1. [General errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336083/11407695)
2. [Service-specific errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62730894/11407695)

---

**What this is not?**

The scope of the Q&A is limited to *common* (not trivial). This is not:

- a catch-all guide or "best practices" collection
- a reference for general ECMAScript errors
- GAS documentation
- a resources list (we have a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for that)

---

**What to add?**

When adding an entry, please, consider the following:

- is the error common enough (see "why" section for examples)?
- can the solution be described concisely and be applicable for most cases?

---

Comment: To those reading or reviewing: please note that the question is a self Q&A and intends to provide detailed answer(-s) for most common issues that are specific to GAS. In preparing to attempt this small project I've read guides on [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as well as [closed-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and didn't find any evidence of being too broad (please, see "no way to determine which" answer is correct in definition close). Moreover, there are lot of examples of similar lists in other tags (feel free to mark as duplicate...

Comment: ...if I missed the definitive guide). Such examples are: [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441049/common-errors-while-writing-android-project), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) to name a few. I also encourage others to take a shot at this and if we are successful I think it would be good idea to make a community wiki out of it.

Comment: I am also aware of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314618/error-reference-collections-bane-or-boon) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149743/php-errors-reference-question) threads and have to clarify (given votes to close as too broad) that the reference is not intended to *replace* answers to the questions but rather as a target for marking such questions as duplicate or referencing in question-specific answer. This reference is also to be extended with references to canonical Q&A as we find them (which is considered a best practice of such collections)

Comment: There aren't "special considerations" for self-answered questions, they should follow the same quality standards than the othert questions ( non-self-answered questions). Related [Is there an etiquette for asking questions originally intended to be self-answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349140/289691)

Comment: @Rubén - sure, although it would be great if we could come to an agreement over what could the question itself contain to not be considered "too broad"? As far as I understood it, there was a "war" several years ago on how such Q&As should be treated and I am not sure about the consensus. Moreover, I noticed that they are getting reopened as of recent (check the ones provided), so decided to give it a shot. I am all for improving the Q&A, but given the primary closure reason "too broad", I am also unsure what *can* be done in that regard...

Comment: I suggest you to post a question on [meta] about this.

Comment: Actually I would like to find an easy to follow ([meta-tag:faq] style) of [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/1595451) (the most-frequent question of [meta-tag:self-answer]).

Comment: @Rubén - I considered this option and decided to wait for an initial response to the Q&A - worth a shot if treaded carefully. Can't recall one as well - the one you linked is close enough, though. The problem is that this one is both a self-answer and a reference, which can prove to be a shot in both feet

Comment: Also, I am thinking on following the footsteps of the other tags and make the question a community wiki as well (which, as it invlolves flagging for custom mod attention, I postponed until the Q&A gets some meat)

Comment: Another related meta Q/A [What to do about hundreds of the same basic question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319930/1595451)

Comment: Maybe a [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) edit with a list of common questions with only links will be better. See [JavaScript tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) for a sample.

Comment: @TheMaster - I think adding a common reference to Q&As to tag info page is a good idea. What would you propose to do with the answers, though - split and republish as standalone Q&As dedicated to a single question - answer pair at a time a-la JS? Actually, it may be a good solution (the only thing left would be to decide what to do with this one)

Comment: I believe split and republish would be good. Although I cast a reopen vote on this question, I agree that the question is too broad and  the answer is highly unlikely to benefit the intended audience. If they had searched for it, they could've found other answers. This answer although helps a bit, they'd still need to scroll through all the error  messages and other noise unneeded for their question.

Comment: @Rubén What do you think about split and republish each question and add a reference to tag page like JavaScript's tag page's faq section?

Comment: @TheMaster - thank you for providing feedback! Seems like that might be the perfect solution - it also deals with the issue of leaving out info to be concise. I am all for it (to finally have an easily identifiable reference point ) and can start doing it one by one if others agree (there are at least 13 Q&As to split into as of now - not sure about quota errors, but we don't have a canonical [at least I don't know of any] for that, so happy to rework and expand). I am also inclined to make them all community wikis with shared guidelines.

Comment: You should also link other valuable answers or make everything community wiki for the tag edit to be accepted by the community.  You don't have to rewrite all questions and answers- maybe answer existing  similar questions.  Otherwise it'll simply look like self promotion. Moderation is key. Just my thoughts

Comment: @TheMaster - yep, just as mentioned was going to make them all community wikis [although making the questions CW will be trickier - as each one has to be custom-converted by a mod as far as I know - I will try to explain that there will be a number of related Q&As, ofc] ("inclined" part was about the shared guidelines). I've started adding other answers in already in the latest edits. This proved to be a bit hard to do, though, as info is very fragmented... I think that tag edit should be done gradually, as the answers get extracted, updated received feedback

Comment: @TheMaster I think that this should be discussed / coordinated on [meta] by one side because in some cases might not be necessary to post a new question but to post a **canonical** answer (also maybe someone could be willing to offer a bounty  for that purpose)

Comment: Posted a question on meta : [What to do with “How to solve common errors in Google Apps Script development”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398230/1595451)

Comment: @Rubén *but to post a canonical answer (also maybe someone could be willing to offer a bounty for that purpose)* I agree and thanks for the meta question.

Comment: @OlegValter That makes sense. Consider commenting on the meta.

Comment: @Rubén - thank you for taking the time to post the meta question. TheMaster - yes, I am actually in the middle of adding that and some other thoughts  as an answer to the question on meta (although not sure - too long to be a comment, but that info is not a full answer either)

Answer (score 6):

**Preface**

The answer provides a guide on *general* errors that can be encountered when working with any Google service (both built-in and advanced) or API. For errors specific to certain services, see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62730894/11407695).

[Back to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336082/how-to-solve-common-errors-in-google-apps-script-development)

---

## General errors

---

**Message**

> TypeError: Cannot read property '`property name here`' from `undefined (or null)`

**Description**

The error message indicates that you are trying to access a property on an `Object` instance, but during *runtime* the value *actually* held by a variable is a special data type `undefined`. Typically, the error occurs when accessing *nested* properties of an object.

A variation of this error with a numeric value in place of property name indicates that an instance of `Array` was expected. As arrays in JavaScript are [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), everything mentioned here is true about them as well.

There is a special case of *dynamically constructed* objects such as [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that are only available in specific contexts like making an HTTP request to the app or invoking a function via time or event-based trigger.

> The error is a [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) because an `"object"` is expected, but `"undefined"` is received

**How to fix**

1. **Using default values**
   [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) `||` operator in JavaScript has an intersting property of evaluating the right-hand side iff the left-hand is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Since objects in JS are truthy, and `undefined` and `null` are falsy, an expression like `(myVar || {}).myProp` [`(myVar || [])[index]` for arrays] will guarantee that no error is thrown and the property is at least `undefined`.

   One can also provide default values: `(myVar || { myProp : 2 })` guarantees accessing `myProp` to return `2` by default. Same goes for arrays: `(myVar || [1,2,3])`.
2. **Checking for type**
   Especially true for the special case,  `typeof` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) combined with an `if` [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) will either allow a function to run outside of its designated context (i.e. for debugging purposes) or introduce branching logic depending on whether the object is present or not.

   One can control how strict the check should be:

- lax ("not undefined"): `if(typeof myVar !== "undefined") { //do something; }`
- strict ("proper objects only"): `if(typeof myVar === "object" && myVar) { //do stuff }`

**Related Q&As**

1. [Parsing order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687907/execution-order-of-gs-files-in-a-project) of the GAS project as the source of the issue

---

**Message**

> Cannot convert `some value` to `data type`

**Description**

The error is thrown due to passing an argument of *different type* than a method expects. A common mistake that causes the error is accidental coercion of a [number to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62246016/how-to-check-if-current-form-submission-is-editing-response).

**How to reproduce**

```
function testConversionError() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("42.0",1);
}
```

**How to fix**

Make sure that the value referenced in the error message is of data type required by documentation and [convert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_conversion) as needed.

---

**Message**

> Cannot call `Service and method name` from this context

**Description**

This error happens on a **context mismatch** and is specific to [container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) scripts.
The primary use case that results in the error is trying to call a method only available *in one document type* (usually, `getUi()` as it is [shared](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) by several services) from another (i.e. `DocumentApp.getUi()` from a spreadsheet).

A secondary, but also prominent case is a result of calling a service [not explicitly allowed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) to be called from a *custom function* (usually a function marked by special JSDoc-style comment `@customfunction` and used as a formula).

**How to reproduce**

For bound script context mismatch, declare and run this function in a script project tied to Google Sheets (or anything other than Google Docs):

```
function testContextMismatch() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getUi();
}
```

Note that calling a `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` will simply result in `null` on mismatch, and the execution *will succeed*.

For custom functions, use the function declared below in any cell as a formula:

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function testConversionError() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(`UI is out of scope of custom function`);
}
```

**How to fix**

1. Context mismatch is easily fixed by changing the service on which the method is called.
2. Custom functions *cannot* be made to call these services, use [custom menus or dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

---

**Message**

> Cannot find method `Method name here`

> The parameters `param names` do not match the method signature for `method name`

**Description**

This error has a notoriously confusing message for newcomers. What it says is that a **type mismatch** occurred in one or more of the arguments passed when the method in question was called.

> There is no method with the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) that corresponds to how you called it, hence "not found"

**How to fix**

The only fix here is to read the documentation carefully and check if order and [inferred type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference#:%7E:text=Type%20inference%20is%20the%20ability,type%20annotations%20having%20been%20given.) of parameters are correct (using a good IDE with autocomplete will help). Sometimes, though, the issue happens because one expects the value to be of a certain type while at *runtime* it is of another. There are several tips for preventing such issues:

1. Setting up type guards (`typeof myVar === "string"` and similar).
2. Adding a validator to fix the type dynamically thanks to JavaScript being [dynamically typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690544/what-is-the-difference-between-a-strongly-typed-language-and-a-statically-typed).

**Sample**

```js
/**
 * @summary pure arg validator boilerplate
 * @param {function (any) : any}
 * @param {...any} args
 * @returns {any[]}
 */
const validate = (guard, ...args) => args.map(guard);

const functionWithValidator = (...args) => {
  const guard = (arg) => typeof arg !== "number" ? parseInt(arg) : arg;

  const [a,b,c] = validate(guard, ...args);
  
  const asObject = { a, b, c };
  
  console.log(asObject);
  
  return asObject;
};

//driver IIFE
(() => {
  functionWithValidator("1 apple",2,"0x5");
})()
```

---

**Messages**

> You do not have permission to perform that action

> The script does not have permission to perform that action

**Description**

The error indicates that one of the APIs or services accessed lacks sufficient permissions from the user. Every service method that has an **authorization** section in its documentation requires at least one of the scopes to be authorized.

As GAS essentially wraps around Google APIs for development convenience, most of the scopes listed in OAuth 2.0 scopes for APIs [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) can be used, although if one is listed in the corresponding docs it may be better to use it as there are some inconsistencies.

Note that custom functions run without authorization. Calling a function from a Google sheet cell is the most common cause of this error.

**How to fix**

If a function calling the service is ran from the script editor, you are automatically prompted to authorize it with relevant scopes. Albeit useful for quick manual tests, it is best practice to [set scopes explicitly](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) in application manifest (appscript.json). Besides, automatic scopes are usually too broad to pass the [review](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) if one intends to publish the app.

The field `oauthScopes` in manifest file (`View -> Show manifest file` if in code editor) should look something like this:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    //etc
  ]
```

For custom functions, you can fix it by switching to calling the function from a menu or a button [as custom functions cannot be authorized](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services).

For those developing [editor Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types#editor_add-ons), this error means an unhandled [authorization lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle) mode: one has to abort before calls to services that require authorization in case auth mode is `AuthMode.NONE`.

**Related causes and solutions**

1. `@OnlyCurrentDoc` [limiting script access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587331/gas-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-openbyid) scope
2. Scopes [autodetection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421055/stopping-the-error-authorisation-is-required-to-perform-that-action-in-google)

---

**Message**

> ReferenceError: `service name` is not defined

**Description**

The most common cause is using an [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) without enabling it. When such a service is enabled, a variable under the specified identifier is attached to [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) that the developer can reference directly. Thus, when a disabled service is referenced, a `ReferenceError` is thrown.

**How to fix**

Go to "Resources -> Advanced Google Services" menu and enable the service referenced. Note that the identifier should equal the global variable referenced.
For a more detailed explanation, read the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

> If one hasn't referenced any advanced services then the error points to an undeclared variable being referenced.

---

**Message**

> The script completed but did not return anything.

> Script function not found: `doGet or doPost`

**Description**

This is not an error per se (as the HTTP response code returned is `200` and the execution is marked as successful, but is commonly regarded as one. The message appears when trying to make a request/access from browser a script [deployed as a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

There are two primary reasons why this would happen:

1. There is no `doGet` or `doPost` trigger function
2. Triggers above *do not return* an `HtmlOutput` or `TextOutput` instance

**How to fix**

For the first reason, simply provide a `doGet` or `doPost` trigger (or both) function. For the second, make sure that all routes of your app end with creation of [`TextOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) or [`HtmlOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output):

```
//doGet returning HTML
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p>Some text</p>");
}

//doPost returning text
function doPost(e) {
  const { parameters } = e;
  const echoed = JSON.stringify(parameters);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(echoed);
}
```

Note that there should be **only one** trigger function declared - treat them as entry points to your application.

If the trigger relies on `parameter` / `parameters` to route responses, make sure that the request URL is structured as "`baseURL`/exec?`query`" or "`baseURL`/dev?`query`" where `query` contains [parameters to pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

**Related Q&As**

1. [Redeploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617138/google-apps-script-function-not-found-doget) after declaring triggers

---

**Message**

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

**Description**

This one is the most cryptic error and can occur at any point with nearly any service (although `DriveApp` usage is particularly susceptible to it). The error usually indicates a problem on Google's side that either goes away in a couple of hours/days or gets fixed in the process.

**How to fix**

There is no silver bullet for that one and usually, there is nothing you can do apart from [filing an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com) on the issue tracker or [contacting support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) if you have a GSuite account. Before doing that one can try the following common remedies:

1. For [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) scripts - creating a new document and copying over the existing project and data.
2. Switch to using an advanced `Drive` [service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) (always remember to enable it first).
3. There might be a [problem with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804649/google-apps-script-were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-please-wait-a-bit-and) if the error points to a line with one.

> Don't bash your head against this error - try locating affected code, file or star an issue and move on

---

**Syntax error without apparent issues**

This error is likely to be caused by using an ES6 syntax (for example, arrow functions) while using the deprecated Rhino runtime (at the time of writing the GAS platform [uses V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#features_of_the_v8_runtime)).

**How to fix**

Open "appscript.json" manifest file and check if `runtimeVersion` is set to `"V8"`, change it if not, or remove any [ES6 features](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp) otherwise.

---

**Quota-related errors**

There are several errors related to quotas imposed on service usage. Google has a [comprehensive list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) of those, but as a general rule of thumb, if a message matches **"too many"** pattern, you are likely to have exceeded the respective quota.

Most likely errors encountered:

- Service invoked too many times: `service name`
- There are too many scripts running
- Service using too much computer time for one day
- This script has too many triggers

**How to fix**

In most cases, the only fix is to wait until the quota is refreshed or switch to another account (unless the script is deployed as a Web App with permission to "run as me", in which case *owner's* quotas will be shared across all users).

To quote documentation at the time:

> Daily quotas are refreshed at the end of a 24-hour window; the exact time of this refresh, however, varies between users.

Note that some services such as `MailApp` have methods like [`getRemainingDailyQuota`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getremainingdailyquota) that can check the remaining quota.

In the case of exceeding the maximum number of triggers one can check how many are installed via [`getProjectTriggers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getprojecttriggers) (or check ["My triggers"](https://script.google.com/home/triggers) tab) and act accordingly to reduce the number (for example, by using [`deleteTrigger(trigger)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deletetriggertrigger) to get rid of some).

**Related canonical Q&As**

1. [How are daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875014/how-does-daily-google-apps-script-quota-limit-apply) limitations being applied and refreshed?
2. "Maximum execution time exceeded" [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854573/exceeded-maximum-execution-time-in-google-apps-script)
3. [Optimizing service calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes/29800759#29800759) to reduce execution time

---

## References

1. How to make error [messages more meaningful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180141/how-do-you-pass-back-a-custom-error-message-from-google-apps-scripts)
2. Debugging [custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288351/debugging-a-custom-function-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: I think related questions can be added for each error something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) for further research.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster - agreed, just posted an initial version to test the waters. Please, let me know if you are aware of any canonical answers / questions. In the meantime I will also be looking both for similar questions and related threads

Comment: @TheMaster - no worries, the reason for the this Q&A was an actual tiredness of seeing the same questions in different flavours - I already made the answer a community wiki, so feel free to edit at your leasure and thank you for supporting the effort.

Answer (score 2):

## Service-specific errors

The answer concerns [built-in service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services)-related errors. For general reference see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62336083/11407695). Entries addressing issues with services [listed in official reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) are welcome.

[Back to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336082/how-to-solve-common-errors-in-google-apps-script-development)

---

#### SpreadsheetApp

> The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

This error is usually caused by calling the `getRange` method where the parameter that sets the number of rows happens to equal to `0`. Be careful if you depend on [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) call return value - only use it on non-empty sheets (`getDataRange` will be safer).

**How to reproduce**

```
sh.getRange(1, 1, 0, sh.getLastColumn()); //third param is the number of rows
```

**How to fix**

Adding a guard that prevents the value from ever becoming `0` should suffice. The pattern below defaults to the last row with data (optional if you only need a certain number of rows) and to `1` if that also fails:

```
//willFail is defined elsewhere
sh.getRange(1, 1, willFail || sh.getLastRow() || 1, sh.getLastColumn());
```

---

> Error: “Reference does not exist”

The error happens when calling a custom function in a spreadsheet cell that [does not return a value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values). The docs do mention only that one "must return a value to display", but the catch here is that an empty array is *also* not a valid return value (no elements to display).

**How to reproduce**

Call the custom function below in any Google Sheets spreadsheet cell:

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
const testReferenceError = () => [];
```

**How to fix**

No specific handling is required, just make sure that `length > 0`.

---

> The number of `rows or cells` in the data does not match the number of `rows or cells` in the range. The data has `N` but the range has `M`.

**Description**

The error points to a *mismatch in dimensions* of range in relation to values. Usually, the issue arises when using `setValues()` method when the matrix of values is smaller or bigger than the range.

**How to reproduce**

```
function testOutOfRange() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const rng = sh.getActiveRange();
    const vals = rng.getValues();
    
    try {
        vals.push([]);
        rng.setValues(vals);
    } catch (error) {
        const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.alert(error.message);
    }
}
```

**How to fix**

If it is **routinely** expected for values to get out of bounds, implement a guard that catches such states, for example:

```
const checkBounds = (rng, values) => {
    const targetRows = rng.getHeight();
    const targetCols = rng.getWidth();

    const { length } = values;
    const [firstRow] = values;

    return length === targetRows &&
        firstRow.length === targetCols;
};
```

---

> The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.

**Description**

The error is a result of a collision between two issues:

1. The `Range` is out of bounds (`getRange()` *does not* throw on requesting a non-existent range)
2. Trying to call a method on a `Range` instance referring to a non-existent dimension of the sheet.

**How to reproduce**

```
function testOB() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rng = sh.getRange(sh.getMaxRows() + 1, 1);
  rng.insertCheckboxes();
}
```

**How to fix**

Check that number of rows ([`getMaxRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)) and columns ([`getMaxColumns()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns)) are both greater or equal to the parameters passed to `getRange()` method call and change them accordingly.

---

> Exception: You can't create a filter in a sheet that already has a filter.

**Description**

The message means that you are trying to call a [`createFilter`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createfilter) method on a `Range` in a `Sheet` that already has a filter set (either via UI or script), thus violating the restriction on 1 filter per `Sheet`, to quote the documentation:

> There can be at most one filter in a sheet.

**How to reproduce**

```
const testFilterExistsError = () => {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  const rng = sh.getDataRange();
  
  const filter1 = rng.createFilter();
  const filter2 = rng.createFilter();
};
```

**How to fix**

Add a guard that checks for the existence of the filter first. [`getFilter`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfilter) returns either a filter or `null` if called on a `Range` instance and is perfect for the job:

```
const testFilterGuard = () => {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  const rng = sh.getDataRange();
  
  const filter = rng.getFilter() || rng.createFilter();
  //do something useful;
};
```

---

#### UrlFetchApp

> Attribute provided with no value: url

**Description**

The error is specific to `UrlFetchApp` service and happens when `fetch` or `fetchAll` method gets called with an empty string or non-string value.

**How to reproduce**

```
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("", {});
```

**How to fix**

Make sure that a string containing a URI (not necessarily valid) is passed to the method as its first argument. As its common root cause is accessing a non-existent property on an [object or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781699/attribute-provided-with-no-value-error-urlfetchapp), check whether your [accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) return an actual value.